# Why remote service is destroyed when main activity is closed?

Tags: android, service

I wrote an android program that: has a main activity for UI, and it starts a service. The service timely callbacks the UI activity to update views. It works fine except: if the activity is closed (with BACK) and start again, the service will also be started again (The service plays audio file, so there are two overlapped sounds).
I use bindService with BIND_AUTO_CREATE flag to start and connect to service. According to the document, it should create service only if it doesn't exist, but obviously it starts another instance when opened second time.
All I want is when the activity is closed, the service goes on running, and when the activity opens again, it can reconnect to the service. Is that possible? Or I just misunderstand the usage of service?

Tried more:
Use ICountService (described in .aidl) instead of CountService in bindService Intent. It's onDestroyed is called when the activity is closed.

Below is code of service creating if it helps.

```
    ServiceConnection conn = new ServiceConnection(){
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName c, IBinder b) {
        Log.d("TK","Connected");
        //binder = (ICountService.Stub) b;
        service = ICountService.Stub.asInterface(b);
        try {
            service.setCallback(new ICountCallback.Stub(){

                @Override
                public void alert() {
                    Log.d("TK","alert!");
                }

                @Override
                public void updateTime(final int sec) {
                    handler.post(new Runnable(){

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                                                            indicator.setText(toText(sec));
                        }

                    });
                }               
            });
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName c) {
        Log.d("TK","Disconnected");
    }           
};

private void startCountService(){
    Intent i = new Intent(ICountService.class.getName());
    boolean ok = context.bindService(i, conn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    Log.d("TK", "bindService="+ok);
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> According to the document, it should create service only if it doesn't exist, but obviously it starts another instance when opened second time.

`bindService()` will create the service instance if the service is not running. `unbindService()` will destroy the service instance if there are no other bound connections and nobody called `startService()`. If the service is destroyed on `unbindService()`, then a subsequent `bindService()` will create a new service instance.

IMHO, ideally, `unbindService()` would not immediately destroy the service, but let it linger for a few seconds first, in case there is a `bindService()` shortly after the `unbindService()`. However, that is not how they implemented it.

> All I want is when the activity is closed, the service goes on running, and when the activity opens again, it can reconnect to the service.

You should be using `startService()` and `stopService()` instead of (or conceivably in addition to) `bindService()` and `unbindService()`.

Comment: Thanks. start/stopService doesn't work. I tried more and found that the service is actually destroyed when activity is closed (CountService.onDestroy is called). The problem now is: How to prevent the service from being destroyed?

Comment: @Reno: Use `startService()`. Believe it or not, it does work.

Comment: Thanks. It finally gets to work. Now I use like this: when start activity, 1) startService, 2) bindService without BIND_AUTO_CREATE; when stop activity, just unbindService, no stopService

Answer (score -2):

This was worked for me.

Main.java

```
public class Main extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        startService(new Intent(Main.this, MyService.class));

        try{

            MyService.setMainActivity(this);

        }catch(Exception e){

            //t.setText(e.getMessage());

        }
     }
}
```

MyService.java

```
public class MyService extends Service {
    private Context ctx;
    public static Main main;
        @Override public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {        
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
        return null;
    }       

    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
        ctx = this; 
        startService();
    } 

    @Override public void onDestroy() {         
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
        Log.d("ASAS","Destroy");
        super.onDestroy();  
    }

    public static void setMainActivity(Main activity) {
        main = activity;
    }

    private void startService()
    {           
        //timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new checkdata(),0,30000);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Should add some explanation to make answer's more helpful.